# How can I pass something like "--yes" to brew in order for it to avoid asking for confirmations?

Tags: homebrew

I haven't found if there's a possibility to pass something like "--yes" to brew so that I won't ask me for confirmations. Is there any way?

Comment: When does Homebrew actually ask for confirmation?

Comment: @nohillside when it's a little drunk

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I‘m using it for years, don‘t remember it ever asking me for anything.

Comment: @nohillside how much would be "a bit more"?

Comment: Can you show a specific example of a `brew` command you run which required you to press `y` during execution?

Comment: @nohillside, no.

Comment: This makes the question a bit hypothetical, somehow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There does not appear to be such a "--yes" parameter, nor something similar for the brew command.

You can consider doing something simple like running the following command:

```
yes | brew <...>
```

However be aware that this will answer "y" to everything automatically.